# How can I fill the Data Attribute of a XAML Path with a desired Icon

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I create the data for a XAML Path for a home icon in xaml?

Comment: Can you precise where you are stuck? What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest checking out this website you can find many icons there:
https://pictogrammers.com/library/mdi/

select the icon you like, navigate to the XML symbol marked with `copy SVG`.
Now paste the svg in notepad. Copy the content of the `d=""` attribute into your paths data="" and you are good to go

[image]

Result:

```
<Path Fill="Black "Data="M19.07,4.93C17.22,3 14.66,1.96 12,2C9.34,1.96 6.79,3 4.94,4.93C3,6.78 1.96,9.34 2,12C1.96,14.66 3,17.21 4.93,19.06C6.78,21 9.34,22.04 12,22C14.66,22.04 17.21,21 19.06,19.07C21,17.22 22.04,14.66 22,12C22.04,9.34 21,6.78 19.07,4.93M17,12V18H13.5V13H10.5V18H7V12H5L12,5L19.5,12H17Z"/>
```

if you want to create resources of this type you can do it like this:

```
<Geometry x:Key="DownArrowThick">M9,4H15V12H19.84L12,19.84L4.16,12H9V4Z</Geometry>
```

and use it like this:

```
<Path Stretch="Fill" Fill="Hotpink" Data="{StaticResource DownArrowThick}"/>
```

[image]

If you do want to create shapes yourself you can imput bitmaps into Inkscape, converti it to a path, merge all paths to a single object and now follow the steps from above to extract the data.

Drawing this data by hand is, while possible rather uncommon.